# How to print this dictionary?

Tags: c#, dictionary

So I have a bit of a complex dictionary:

```
Dictionary<string, Dictionary< string, HashSet< string >>>
```

How can I print its keys and values?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
//example
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;

class Program
{
    static void Main()
    {
        var dic = new Dictionary<string, Dictionary<string,HashSet<string>>>
        {
            {"k", new Dictionary<string,HashSet<string>>
                {
                    {"k1", new HashSet<string>{"a","b","c"}}
                }
            },
            {"k3", new Dictionary<string,HashSet<string>>
                {
                    {"k4", new HashSet<string>{"1","2","3"}}
                }
            }

        };

        foreach(var p in dic)
        {
            Console.Write(p.Key + " -- ");
            foreach(var p1 in p.Value)
            {
                Console.Write(p1.Key + " -- ");
                foreach(var str in p1.Value)
                {
                    Console.Write(str + " ");
                }
            }
            Console.WriteLine();
        }
    } 
}
output: k -- k1 -- a b c
        k3 -- k4 -- 1 2 3
```

Comment: This throws an invalid argument error in the second foreach loop on (dic[key]).

Comment: How is this better than my answer?

Comment: @Rariolu OP says "So I have a bit of a complex dictionary:" and he doesn't know how to print it out. I think he knows how to print a simple `Dictionary<string,string>`

Answer (score 0):

To get all values into a string, you could use this

```
Dictionary<string,string> dictionary;
//[...]

string output = "";
foreach(string key in dictionary.Keys)
{
    output += "\nKey: \""+key+"\" Value: \""+dictionary[key]+"\"";
}
MessageBox.Show(output);
```

I imagine you'd wanna tweak the format but this should help.